# optparse-applicative: How to handle no-arguments situation in Arrow syntax

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, applicative, arrows, optparse-applicative

There is example: https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative/blob/master/tests/Examples/Cabal.hs#L46-L62

```
parser :: Parser Args
parser = runA $ proc () -> do
  opts <- asA commonOpts -< ()
  cmds <- (asA . hsubparser)
            ( command "install"
              (info installParser
                    (progDesc "Installs a list of packages"))
           <> command "update"
              (info updateParser
                    (progDesc "Updates list of known packages"))
           <> command "configure"
              (info configureParser
                    (progDesc "Prepare to build the package"))
           <> command "build"
              (info buildParser
                    (progDesc "Make this package ready for installation")) ) -< ()
  A version >>> A helper -< Args opts cmds
```

...

```
pinfo :: ParserInfo Args
pinfo = info parser
  ( progDesc "An example modelled on cabal" )

main :: IO ()
main = do
  r <- execParser pinfo
  print r
```

So and by default when I don't use arguments it shows Usage info. I want to use case with no arguments, and also with one [Custom argument] (with custom one I'm getting error: `Invalid argument 'regreg'`)

How can I handle empty and custom arguments here?

Answer (score 4):

`A` in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.11.0.2/docs/Options-Applicative-Arrows.html isn't [ArrowPlus](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowPlus). I'm not sure if it can be (given that `f` is `Alternative`), but for now you have to use `Alternative` syntax:

```
subparser (command "foo" ... ...) <|> pure DefaultCommand
```